# Destroying TypeScript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, babeljs, linter

I'm working using Meteor/React using Visual Studio Code but I cannot get rid of those errors:

Eg.: visual studio code

> Cannot find module 'meteor/mongo'

*(see screenshot: [Cannot find module ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIGzu.jpg))*

If I write at the beginning of the file

```
// @ts-nocheck
```

The error disappear

My question here is, why TS? does this TypeScript means?? I'm not doing anything in TypeScript. Im writing Javascript ES6 Code.
Here my jsconfig.json:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

How to delete/disable/destroy TypeScript ??

Comment: Did you run `npm install` after creating the app?

Comment: Hello Chris G.of curse I did a npm install. But the Word TypeScript is a Tabu in my Project. There is nowhere a mention.

Answer (score 0):

It's just using tsserver to validate your Javascript imports. So it's really Javascript validation.

If you don't want it you can remove your checkJs parameter.